# ?Getting datatables.js horizontal scrolling with fixed columns to work on mobile?

Tags: datatables

Is there a trick to getting datatables.js horizontal scrolling with fixed columns to work on mobile?  Things work great on desktop or in chrome-dev with dimensions of an iphone, but when actually viewing on an iphone, scrolling horizontally moves the entire table and the fixed columns don't work.

Answer (score 0):

OK - the issue here was that things were in an iframe, and mobile browsers seem to take control of sizing of iframes and this is what was causing the problem.

Adding an inner div and some css per https://davidwalsh.name/scroll-iframes-ios seemed to address it.